# Hypothesis Testing problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The population is divided into three levels of education level viz under-graduate graduate and post graduate and the proportion is expected to be 1:4:3 respectively.A sample of 210 graduates and 135 post graduates while remaining were
under graduates . Test the hypothesis that proportion is unchanged at 5% level of significance?

Comment: Ok..... what have you tried ??

Comment: I am confused to use chi square or difference between proportion..